# Store OpenCV::Mat to SQLite DB as BLOB

Tags: c++, sqlite, opencv, blob

Is it possible to store image from opencv::Mat to sqlite database (as BLOB or other type)?
I can store other variable like string, but not the cv::Mat in. 
Here is my function code

```
void SQLiteWrapper::WriteDetectInfo(std::string markName, std::string dmgClass, cv::Mat in)
{
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    std::ostringstream strQuery;

    strQuery << "INSERT INTO DetectedDamage(Markname, Class, Image)";
    strQuery << "VALUES('" << markName;
    strQuery << "','" << dmgClass;
    strQuery << "'," << in;
    strQuery << ");";
    std::string query = strQuery.str();
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(DB3, query.c_str(), SQLiteWrapper::CallBack, (void*)CB_WRITE_DETECT_INFO, &zErrMsg);
}
```

Comment: Use a prepared statement with parameters for the columns you're inserting, and bind the appropriate values to those. See https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

For storing an image as BLOB you need to convert the mat to `char*` first. For this purpose you can use [`cv::imencode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imencode). and then you can insert the blob data as:

```
int rc = 0;
char* buffer = new char[size]; // Your image data from `cv::imencode()`

sqlite3_stmt *strQuery = NULL;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,"INSERT INTO DetectedDamage(Markname, Class, Image) VALUES (NULL, NULL, ?)", -1, &strQuery, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_blob(strQuery, 1, buffer, size, SQLITE_STATIC);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    std::cerr << "bind failed!" << std::endl;
} else {
    rc = sqlite3_step(strQuery);
    if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
        std::cerr << "execution failed!" << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << std::endl;
}
```